# Is there a cross-platform way to reliably find the stdout file descriptor with ctypes?

Tags: python, macos, posix, ctypes, darwin

I have some code that uses ctypes to try to determine if the file pointed to by `sys.stdout` is *actually* `stdout`.  I know that on any POSIX-compliant system, and even on Windows, it should be safe to assume this is true if `sys.stdout.fileno() == 1`, so my question is not how to do this in general.

In my code (which is already using ctypes for something unrelated to my question) I carelessly had something like:

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('c'))
real_stdout = libc.fileno(ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout'))
if sys.stdout.fileno() == real_stdout:
    ...
```

This works perfectly fine on Linux, so I didn't really think about it much.  It looked nicer and more readable than hard-coding `1` as the file descriptor.  But I found a few days later that my code wasn't working on OSX.

It turns outs OSX's libc doesn't export any symbol called 'stdout'.  Instead its stdio.h has stdout defined as:

```
#define stdout __stdoutp
```

If I change my code to `c_void_p.in_dll(libc, '__stdoutp')` my code works as expected, but of course that's OSX-only.  Windows, it turns out, has a similar issue (at least if using MSVC).

I will probably just change my code to use `1`, but my question still stands, out of curiosity, if there's a cross-platform way to get the `stdio` pointer (and likewise `stdin` and `stderr`) without *assuming* that it's using the POSIX-compliant descriptor?

Comment: A "file descriptor" isn't a cross-platform concept. It's a Posix-specific. You can use `fileno(stdout)` on any Posix platform, though there's a also a predefined macro for that value named `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: note that if `sys.stdout` has been replaced the original `stdout` remains in `sys.__stdout__` (unless your code changes that too). See that `sys.__stdout__.fileno()` => `1`

Comment: note that file decriptors (an integer "handle") is a very different thing than the stdout FILE* in C. There's no cross platform ABI for the symbols found in C libraries, so taking that path is futile. Hard coding 1 as the file descriptor for stdout would be almost infinitely more portable.

Comment: `sys.__stdout__.fileno()` can't be relied on either since it can just as easily be replaced.  nos understood the question, but as I suspected there's no good answer really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As so often when it comes to C, if you want compatibility, you'll have to go and look in the relevant standard. Since you mention windows, I guess you're not actually wanting the POSIX standard, but rather the C one.

C99 section 7,19,1 defines stdout to be a macro, and thus not a variable. That means there's no way you can rely on finding it using dlsym (which I assume in_dll uses). The actual expression could just as well be a function call or a fixed address. Perhaps not very likely, but it is possible...

As said in the comments, the fileno function is in turn defined by POSIX, not by C. C has no concept of file descriptors. I think you're better off assuming POSIX and just checking for the value 1, which it specifies.

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer, as most of what I was looking for is confirmation of what I already knew.  Though I didn't know that the C standard defined it as a macro--that confirms more than anything that there's no real answer to this problem.  And you're right--it would probably have been more straightforward to ask this question in terms of dlsym, which ctypes is using under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

If you're simply interested in making things work, rather than strict standards adherence (like me), you can find the "real" name of stdout by writing a simple C snippet:

```
echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\nFILE* mystdout = stdout;' > test.c
cpp test.c | tail
```

Gives you the output:

```
FILE* mystdout = __stdoutp;
```

This means that you also need to try `ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, '__stdoutp')` to cover the case of darwin.

Comment: That's a neat and straightforward trick; would be helpful for finding things like this in the future.